# How do I reverse a filter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How would I write a function "reverse" that would filter the elements not filtered by the original filter?
I feel like it should be simple but I can't think of a solution.

```
let f1 = e => e > 3;

let f2 = reverse(f1);

let filteredarr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(f2);

console.log(filteredarr); // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might try negating the boolean of the current filter... As an aside, consider more descriptive function names than `f1` and `f2`. `reverse` isn't shown so it's not really clear what it does, although it's possible it negates the result of the function parameter. If so, then don't use it and you'll get the opposite of `f2`.

Comment: @ggorlen I think OP wants to know how `reverse` should be implemented. I don't believe it exists yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling that you're looking for a more general-purpose function that you can pass any other function to. In that case, it's *slightly* more complicated, but not hugely.

```js
// Perhaps opposite is a better name, since .reverse already exists
const opposite = f => ((...args) => !f(...args));

const predicate = e => e > 3;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr.filter(predicate));
console.log(arr.filter(opposite(predicate)));
```

Basically, `opposite` is a function that **returns another function**, and that returned function's return value is the boolean negative of the first function's return value.

The `...` is called the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and, in this case, it tells JavaScript to both take an arbitrary number of arguments and send through the same arbitrary number of parameters.

---

Of course, if you're **not** looking for a general purpose solution, then the easier route is to simply negate the return value of your function in-place in the `.filter` call:

```js
const predicate = e => e > 3;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr.filter(predicate));
console.log(arr.filter((...args) => !predicate(...args)));
```

Comment: Maybe it might be better to use rest-parameters here in case the predicate takes in more arguments other than just the current item (such as the index) eg: `const opposite = fn => (...args) => !fn(...args);`

Comment: @NickParsons Good point, how could I have forgotten? I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Man, you guys are so cool. I wish I am as smart as you guys.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for.

```js
// Predicate
const isLargerThan3 = number => number > 3;

const reversePredicate = predicate => number => !predicate(number);

const filteredArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(reversePredicate(isLargerThan3));

console.log(filteredArray);
```